# Incoming SMTP to Azure Windows VM going to C:\inetpub\mailroot\Queue\ instead of Drop\

Tags: windows, email, smtp, email-server, azure

I have an ASP.NET web app that needs to process incoming SMTP email from any Internet user.

I configured IIS and my Azure Windows server 2012 R2 VM end point, but when I send email from the Internet, it gets received in C:\inetpub\mailroot\Queue\ and not C:\inetpub\mailroot\Drop like it used to back when I ran the app on my own server running Windows server 2008 R2.

Also, when the web app tries to access the .EML SMTP files from Queue\ it usually gets error "in use by another".

My understanding is the Queue\ is for outgoing SMTP that is delayed, and Drop\ is for all incoming SMTP.

How do I get my incoming SMTP to go to Drop\ ?

Comment: Do you have a local domain set up?

Comment: I don't know.  I never set one up.